# Adding multiple columns in a spotfire custom expression

Tags: spotfire

I am trying to create a button to change a bar chart to switch between 2 columns on the y axis (side by side bars) and 1 column.
First option of toggle:
[image: First option of toggle]
Second option of toggle:
[image: Second option of toggle]
I am using a button that increments a document property by 1 each time it is clicked, and a custom expression for the y axis which checks the value of the document property and changes the axis accordingly.
The custom expression is an if statement, checking if it is odd or even, and then changing the columns.
(Side note - I have not tried solving this using an iron python script)

I tried

```
If( ${DocProp} % 2 = 0, (UniqueCount([moa]) , UniqueCount([jp_cluster])),(UniqueCount([moa])))
```

But received the error:

```
Expected ')' but found ',' on line 1 character 37.
```

I knew the comma between the two columns might cause a problem by interfering with the if statement, so I tried a case statement:

```
case ${RemoveJPCluster} % 2 when 0 then (UniqueCount([moa]), UniqueCount([jp_cluster])) else UniqueCount([moa]) end
```

But this throws the same error:

```
Expected ')' but found ',' on line 1 character 44.
```

I have also tried:
+
AND
NEST

Any help on this? Is it even possible? I don't know why I can't surround the two columns with brackets and call it a day...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why that does not work, probably as you suspect the comma gets in the way.

Instead of creating a *DocProp* with values 1 or 2,
you could directly put the desired expressions in it.
So you add a text area with a drop down list assigned to DocProp.

Set property value through:  Fixed values, then assign two entries as:

Display Name: 1 (or whatever you want)

Value: UniqueCount([moa])

Display Name: 2

Value: UniqueCount([moa]), UniqueCount([jp_cluster])

Then populate your Value Axis with ${DocProp} directly.

Comment: When I do this the visualisation 'cannot find the column'. When I just used "moa" as the value, it worked for only moa but not for both: it tries to find a column called "moa, jp_cluster". I have tried other work-arounds like manually typing in "moa, table_name.jp_cluster", but it still tries to find a column with the name of that string. It needs a way to distinguish I need two separate columns...

Comment: My example worked. I cannot see a way that it looked for a column called "moa, jp_cluster". Have you set it up the exact way I did?

Comment: It has now worked! I previously chose 'Set from property' in the column axis - but when I looked at the expression, it had $esc in front of it: I don't know what this does, but when I removed it, it now works. Sorry for the confusion and thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found was making an ironpython script

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import *
Document.Properties["DocProp"] += 1
myVis = myVis.As[Visualization]()
if Document.Properties["DocProp"] % 2 == 0:
    myVis.YAxis.Expression = "UniqueCount([moa])"
else:
    myVis.YAxis.Expression =  '$map("UniqueCount($csearch([table_name],"mcbcce*"))",",")'
```

This is attached to a button and changes the columns when DocProp changes.

The problem that was solved was on line 7:

I created 2 calculated columns, which just renamed the columns with this prefix: 'mcbcce'.

I then used csearch to select these columns, which outputted them as two separate columns.

Finally I used 'map' to assign the UniqueCount aggregation to both of them.